# Proof of a logarithmic and algebraic fact

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Recently I'm facing a logarithmic problem and this is in the following.
If I'm given $\frac{ab\log_k{ab}}{a+b}=\frac{bc\log_k{bc}}{b+c}=\frac{ca\log_k{ca}}{c+a}$
How can I prove this fact
$a^a=b^b=c^c$
Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

$$F=\frac{ab\log_k(ab)}{a+b}=\frac{\log_ka+\log_kb}{1/a+1/b}=\cdots$$

Now if $G=\dfrac ab=\dfrac cd=\dfrac ef=\cdots$

we can prove, $G=\dfrac{xa+yc+ze+\cdots}{xb+yd+zf+\cdots}$

$$\implies F=\dfrac{\log_ka+\log_kb+\log_kb+\log_kc-(\log_kc+\log_ka)}{1/a+1/b+1/b+1/c-\left(1/c+1/a\right)}=\dfrac{\log_kb}{1/b}=\log_k(b^b)$$